# How to build installer of some files?

Tags: windows, installation

I have some files on my laptop,
I need to build program.exe installer or program.msi installer.

Purpose is:

-When pressing that program.exe, it must release one file to  C: disk,
 and other file to desktop.

How can I do it? Where can I find this program?

Thanks too much!

Comment: You should basically never install files to the root directory of a disk. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: I know, but I do want it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I use [inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to built my installers. The installers are generated from scripts. I would imagine yours will be fairly small, just specify the source file and where you would want it to be installed, hit "compile" and it'll build your installer for you.